# Python counting the unique occurences of a string in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m trying to count the unique IP addresses in a Apache log-file using python 3.3.1
The thing is I don’t think that it is counting everything correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
from collections import Counter

#
# This function counts the unique IP adresses in the logfile
#
def print_unique_ip(logfile):
    IPset = set()
    for line in logfile:
        head, sep, tail = line.partition(" ")
        if(len(head) > 1):
            IPset.update(head)

    print(len(IPset))
    return  

#
# This is the main function of the program
#
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="An appache log file processor")

    parser.add_argument('-l', '--log-file', help='This is the log file to work on', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-n', help='Displays the number of unique IP adresses', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-t', help='Displays top T IP adresses', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-v', help='Displays the number of visits of a IP adress')

    arguments = parser.parse_args()

    if(os.path.isfile(arguments.log_file)):
        logfile = open(arguments.log_file)
    else:
        print('The file <', arguments.log_file, '> does not exist')
        sys.exit

    if(arguments.n == True):
        print_unique_ip(logfile)
    if(arguments.t):
        print_top_n_ip(arguments.t, logfile)
    if(arguments.v):
        number_of_ocurrences(arguments.v, logfile)

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I have left put everything else.

When I run it I get

```
$ python3 assig4.py -l apache_short.log -n
12
```

But I know that there are more than 12 unique IPs in the file

It doesn’t seem to be giving me the right result. What I am trying to do is to read the file line by line, then when I find an IP address I put it into a set as it only saves unique elements and then I print out the length of said set.

Comment: It could be useful knowing the number that you are expecting to get, might see the bug quicker.

Comment: I don't know what the bug is, but can't you rewrite `if(not(len(head) <= 1)):` as `if len(head)>1`?

Comment: I don't actually know how many IPs are in the file exactly as it is a file I got with the assignment and it is 778108 lines long. I only did a quick count and found more than 12 IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IPset.update(head)
```

Bug.  This will not do what you're expecting.  You want to `add` each IP to your set instead.  Examples make it clearest:

```
>>> s1 = set()
>>> s2 = set()
>>> s1.add('11.22.33.44')
>>> s2.update('11.22.33.44')
>>> s1
set(['11.22.33.44'])
>>> s2
set(['1', '3', '2', '4', '.'])
```

Comment: This is not a bug.  `update` is equivalent to `add` when the argument is a scalar.

Comment: The argument is a string.

Comment: Yes, I would hope that's obvious.  The bug is that the OP expected `update` to add the whole string to his `set` when actually it adds each character from the string.

Comment: The bug is in the fact that he has never opened the file!  `for line in logfile` actually cycles over characters in the string `openfile` itself!

Comment: Uh no?  I see `logfile = open(arguments.log_file)` in `main`.  Weird way of doing things, yes, but it opens the file, and `line` is indeed a line.  I'm afraid you're just strictly incorrect.  The bug is his usage of `update`, not in opening/iterating over the file.

Comment: I'm quite new to python, normally code in c or java. As a matter of fact this is my first program that I'm making and there is a lot of Google and reading notes involved. What would be a better way of doing it? I thought since I'm using that file everywhere that I would open it in main.

Comment: @KaiUR you can open a file as many times as you want, there's basically no overhead involved in doing so.  Usually in python we use context managers to do the opening so it handles closing the file when we're done.  `with open(myfile) as f:  ... for line in f: ...`